# Find the current frame label of a movieclip inside a movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I'm making a game and I need to find the currentFrame of a movieclip inside the movieclip.

This is what should happen:

I have a box(movieclip) called "kaas" that has 2 movieclips inside it.
at the startup of the stage it stays on frameLabel "heel".
When you collide(jump) into "kaas", it should play the frameLabel "kapot", which it does.
If the currentFrame of the frameLabel "kapot" is frame 52 it should removeChild "kaas" and that is where the problem is, I have no clue how to detect which framelabel "kapot" is currently at.

Now I have tried a view things with currentFrame and currentFrameLabel, but without succes.

Here is the part as of now:

```
                if (player.hitTestObject(kaas)) {
                    yVel = 3;
                    player.x += xVel + 2;
                    kaas.gotoAndStop("kapot"); // als je het blokje raakt.
                    if (kaas.currentFrame == 52){ // this is the part where I try to check the current frame of "kapot".
                        removeChild(kaas);
                    }
                }
```

The error I get is that I can't direct to an object that is null. (error #1009).

Now my question is how I would make a working check(if statement) for this.

With kind regards,
Remy

Answer (score 1):

A few possible cases:

- the movieclip that contains the object is playing, changing to a frame that doesn't contain the object anymore (so the attribute becomes `null`)
- this object has the instance name in one frame, but not in the other, so it becomes `null` when the second frame is playing
- some other part of the code explicitly set it to `null`
- you are targeting Flash Player 9, where the display objects are loaded asynchronously to your `gotoAndStop` call. This means it takes a while to the objects to get initialized, and before that you are stuck with nulls. Solution is to target Flash Player 10 or 11 (change it in Publish Settings [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>]). If you really need to target Flash Player 9, [there are convoluted methods to ensure the attributes are accessible](http://www.lecrabe.net/wordpress/?p=42)

(By the way, could you translate the frame labels, comments and variable names? It's distracting and sometimes hides useful information.)